# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key action

Tags: ios, swift

aim new to Xcode and Swift. I tried to code an App just out of a tutorial. I just getting the same Error and can't parse ist to a fix.

> currency Converter[6086:1213367] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key action.'

Here is my Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{

    var myCurrency:[String] = []
    var myValues:[Double] = []

    var activeCurrency:Double = 0;

    //Objects s ss

    @IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!


    //creating pickerView
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return myCurrency.count
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return myCurrency[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
       return activeCurrency = myValues[row]
    }
    //Button

    @IBAction func action(_ sender: UIButton) {
        output.text = String(Double(input.text!)!*activeCurrency)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // getting DATA
        let url = URL(string: "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=0e1cd6f819da83ba29ec67a7060e8b47")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("ERROR")
            }
            else {
                if let content = data
                {
                    do{
                        let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                        if let rates = myJson["rates"] as? NSDictionary
                        {
                            for (key,value) in rates{
                                self.myCurrency.append((key as? String)!)
                                self.myValues.append((value as? Double)!)

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch{

                    }
                }
            }
            self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        }
        task.resume()
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Wow, i just found the solution.. 
i forgot to reference the Button

```
  //Objects s ss

@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var action: UIButton!
```

Answer (score -2):

Please check your IBOutlets/IBActions and see if they are mis-referenced.